# how to change Razorpay total amount decimal value to actual price

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, razorpay

View

```
def Checkout(request):
    amount_str = request.POST.get('amount')
    amount_float = float(amount_str)
    amount = int(amount_float)
    cart = request.session.get('cart')
    tax = sum(i.get('tax', 0) for i in cart.values() if i)


    payment = client.order.create(
        {
            "amount": amount, 
            "currency": "INR",
            "payment_capture" : "1"
        }
    )
    
    order_id = payment['id']

    context = {
        'tax' : tax,
        'order_id' : order_id,
        'payment' : payment,
    }
    return render(request, 'checkout/checkout.html', context)
```

```
<form action="{% url 'success' %}" method="post">
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
var options = {
    "key": "rzp_test_05AdCyeNjGQqYO", 
    "amount": "50000", 
    "currency": "INR",
    "name": "Acme Corp", //your business name
    "description": "Test Transaction",
    "image": "https://example.com/your_logo",
    "order_id": "{{order_id}}", 
    "callback_url": "http://localhost:8000/success/",
    "prefill": { //We recommend using the prefill parameter to auto-fill customer's contact information especially their phone number
        "name": "Gaurav Kumar", //your customer's name
        "email": "gaurav.kumar@example.com",
        "contact": "9000090000" //Provide the customer's phone number for better conversion rates 
    },
    "notes": {
        "address": "Razorpay Corporate Office"
    },
    "theme": {
        "color": "#3399cc"
    }
};
var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
document.getElementById('rzp-button1').onclick = function(e){
    rzp1.open();
    e.preventDefault();
}
</script>
</form>
```

Here im trying to integrate the razorpay its working. but the problem is im tryig to fetch the total amount of the user wants to pay . but in this case it is showing as an decimal value 647.99 but my actual total amount is 64799. How to fix this problem?

The below image is the output

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuUWD.png)

Answer (score 1):

Need to convert paisa to rupee `(100 paisa *100) = 1 rupee`

#### views.py

```
def CheckoutView(request):
    usr = request.user
    cutomer_data = CustomerModel.objects.filter(user=usr)
    product_data = Cart.objects.filter(user=usr)
    cart_count = Cart.objects.filter(user=usr).count()
    productamount = 0
    shipping_amt = 40
    final_amt = 0
    data = Cart.objects.filter(user=usr)
    for i in product_data:
        prod_amt = ((i.product.price)*(i.quantity))
        productamount += prod_amt
        final_amt = productamount+shipping_amt
    # Payment script Start
    client = razorpay.Client(auth=("your id", "your secret"))
    payment = client.order.create({'amount':(final_amt)*100, 'currency': 'INR','payment_capture': '1'})
    # Payment script End 
    context = {'cutomer_data': cutomer_data, 'product_data': product_data,
               'productamount': productamount, 'shipping_amt': shipping_amt, 
               'final_amt': final_amt,'cart_count':cart_count,'payment':payment}
    return render(request, 'checkout.html', context)
```

#### script

```js
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
    data-key="your id"
    data-amount="{{amount}}"
    data-currency="INR"
    data-order_id="{{payment.id}}"
    data-buttontext="Pay with Razorpay"
    data-name="Your Brand Name"
    data-description="Clothing"
    data-image="https://example.com/your_logo.jpg"
    data-prefill.name="PC"
    data-prefill.email="youremail@email.com"
    data-theme.color="#F37254">
</script>
```

Comment: Sir can you please check my new question

Comment: above answer is working or not ??

Comment: I changed my code so here I got the new problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76712175/how-to-get-the-total-amount-of-the-product-in-razorpay-in-django