# How to get the total amount of the product in razorpay in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, razorpay

Html

```
<td>
                        {% if cart_total_amount > 3000 %}
                        <ul>
                            <li class="fw-bold text-end me-2 mt-3"> <label class="border border-white shadow-sm p-2 mb-2 bg-body rounded">₹{{cart_total_amount|add:tax}}</label></li>
                        </ul>   
                        {% else %}

                        <ul>
                           <li class="fw-bold text-end me-2 mt-3"> <label class="border border-white shadow-sm p-2 mb-2 bg-body rounded"> ₹{{cart_total_amount|add:tax|add:10}}</label></li>
                       </ul>  
                       {% endif %}

                    </td>
                      <a id="rzp-button1" class="tp-btn-h1 mt-4" >Place Order</a>
```

```
<form action="{% url 'success' %}" method="post">
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
var options = {
    "key": "rzp_test_05AdCyeNjGQqYO", 
    "amount": "{{amount}}", 
    "currency": "INR",
    "name": "Opencart", 
    "description": "Pay your amount with razorpay",
    "image": "https://example.com/your_logo",
    "order_id": "{{order_id}}", 
    "callback_url": "http://localhost:8000/success/",
    "prefill": { //We recommend using the prefill parameter to auto-fill customer's contact information especially their phone number
        "name": " Vishnu ", //your customer's name
        "email": "vishnu.s@example.com",
        "contact": "9000090000" //Provide the customer's phone number for better conversion rates 
    },
    "notes": {
        "address": "Razorpay Corporate Office"
    },
    "theme": {
        "color": "#3399cc"
    }
};
var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
document.getElementById('rzp-button1').onclick = function(e){
    rzp1.open();
    e.preventDefault();
}
</script>
</form>
```

View

```
def Checkout(request):
    amount_str = request.POST.get('amount')
    amount = int(float(amount_str) * 100)
    cart = request.session.get('cart')
    tax = sum(i.get('tax', 0) for i in cart.values() if i)


    payment = client.order.create(
        {
            "amount": amount, 
            "currency": "INR",
            "payment_capture" : "1"
        }
    )
    
    order_id = payment['id']

    context = {
        'tax' : tax,
        'order_id' : order_id,
        'payment' : payment,
    }
    return render(request, 'checkout/checkout.html', context)
```

View

```
def PlaceOrder(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uid = request.session.get('_auth_user_id')
        user = User.objects.get(id = uid)
        cart = request.session.get('cart')
        print(cart)
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        address = request.POST.get('address')
        city = request.POST.get('city')
        district = request.POST.get('district')
        postcode = request.POST.get('postcode')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        amount = request.POST.get('amount')
       

        order_id = request.POST.get('order_id')
        tax = sum(i.get('tax', 0) for i in cart.values() if i)

        total_amount = 0 

        payment = request.POST.get('payment')

        
        context = {
            'order_id' : order_id,
            'tax' : tax,
            
        }

        order = Order(
            user = user,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            address = address,
            city = city,
            district = district,
            postcode = postcode,
            email = email,
            phone = phone,
            payment_id = order_id,
            amount = amount,
            
        )
        order.save()
        
        for i in cart:

            a = cart[i]['price']
            b = cart[i]['quantity']
            tax = sum(i.get('tax', 0) for i in cart.values() if i)

            print(type(a))
            print(type(b))

            item_total = a * b + tax  
            total_amount += item_total
            

            item = OrderItem(
                order = order,
                product = cart[i]['product_name'],
                quantity = cart[i]['quantity'],
                price = cart[i]['price'],
                total = item_total
                
            )
            item.save()
            total = total_amount + tax  amount

            context['total'] = total  
        
        return render(request, 'checkout/placeorder.html', context)
```

Here I'm trying to implement razor pay integration. here one of my mobile phone's prices is ₹62042 and
adding the tax amount and shipping charge. so the tax is 10rs in this case so the total amount should be ₹62052. the shipping charge is only applicable for the product that is less than 3000 so add the shipping charge as 10rs. that was checking in my html code.

The problem is for payment with Razorpay it shows only the product amount of ₹62042 I want to get the total amount(₹62052). how to solve this

[razorpay output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwicD.png)